# Помогите сделать поиск людей для бота вк, python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть бот для вк, нужно сделать так, чтобы он сохранял данные, которые вводит пользователь. Если нажать кнопку "создать пати", то человек выбирает игру, вводит ФИО, дискорд, игровой уровень. По этим параметрам бот должен искать напарника по этой игре(также удалять данные человека, которые он ввёл через 2 дня после ввода).

Если нажимаем на кнопку "найти пати", то по конкретной игре выводим все существующие команды людей

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import random
import os

os.chdir(r'D:\project')
open('keyboard.json')

os.chdir(r'D:\project')
open('keyboard_genres.json')

os.chdir(r'D:\project')
open('keyboard_start.json')


vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = "***")
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)

vk = vk.get_api()

def random_id():
    Random = 0
    Random += random.randint(0, 10000000)
    return Random

while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
            if event.text.lower() == "привет":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'Привет, нажми на кнопку "старт"',
                    keyboard = open("keyboard_start.json", 'r', encoding="utf-8").read(),
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text.lower() == "старт":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'что будем делать?',
                    keyboard = open("keyboard.json", 'r', encoding="utf-8").read(),
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text.lower() == "найти пати":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'во что будем играть?',
                    keyboard = open("keyboard_genres.json", 'r', encoding="utf-8").read(),
                    random_id = random_id()
                )

                #поиск команд игроков
                
            elif event.text.lower() == "создать пати":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'во что будем играть?',
                    keyboard = open("keyboard_genres.json", 'r', encoding="utf-8").read(),
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text.lower() == "стратегия":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = "выберите игру:\n\n Dota 2 - Dota\nLeague of Legends - LOL\nSid Meier's Civilization VI - SMC\nStellaris - Stell\nTotal War: WARHAMMER II - TWW\nWorld of Warcraft - WOW",
                   random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text.lower() == "выживание":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = "выберите игру:\n\n Dead by Daylight - DBD\n⛏Minecraft - MINE\n⚒Rust - Rust\nTerraria - TERR\n‍♂Unturned - UNT",
                   random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text.lower() == "шутер":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = "выберите игру:\n\n Counter-Strike: Global Offensive - CSGO\nSource SDK Base 2007 - SDK\nCrossout - CR\nDestiny 2 - Destiny\nEscape from Tarkov - EFT\nHalo: The Master Chief Collection - HALO\nPLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS - PUBG\nTeam Fortress 2 - TF2\nTom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege - TCRSS\nValorant - Val\nWar Thunder - WT\nWorld of Tanks - WOT\n☄Warframe - WARF",
                    random_id = random_id()
                )    
            elif event.text.lower() == "rp":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = "выберите игру:\n\n Grand Theft Auto V - GTA5\n⚙Garry's Mod - GM\nGrand Theft Auto SA - GTASA",
                   random_id = random_id()
                ) 
            elif event.text.lower() == "назад":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'во что будем играть?',
                    keyboard = open("keyboard.json", 'r', encoding="utf-8").read(),
                   random_id = random_id()   
                )
            elif event.text == "Dota":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку, ФИО, discord, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "LOL":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "SMC":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "Stell":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "TWW":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "WOW":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "DBD":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "MINE":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "Rust":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "TERR":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "UNT":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "CSGO":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "SDK":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "CR":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, ровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )   
            elif event.text == "Destiny":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "EFT":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "HALO":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "PUBG":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "TF2":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "TCRSS":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "Val":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "WT":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "WOT":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "WARF":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "GTA5":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "GM":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
            elif event.text == "GTASA":
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'введите по порядку discord, ФИО, уровень персонажа, доп. информацию(по вашему усмотрению) : ',
                    random_id = random_id()
                )                                  
            else:
                vk.messages.send(
                    user_id = event.user_id,
                    message = 'не понел', 
                    random_id = random_id()
                )
```

Comment: Ну, делайте, раз нужно. А сюда приходят с конкретными вопросами.